# Not being able to add vertical line in flutter

Tags: flutter, layout

I have the following layout

```
Form(
  onChanged: _updateFormProgress,
  child: Row(       
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ....
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ...
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I need a vertical separator line beteen the two `Expanded`

I tried:

```
Form(
  onChanged: _updateFormProgress,
  child: Row(       
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ....
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 1,
        )
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ...
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

And it compiles but I can't see the line. I also tried other options like wrapping the Expanded in a Container and make a border but have different issues with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed code like tree you provide, and change it to work.

Please wrap 'Row' with 'IntrinsicHeight'.

[image]

I attached full code I tested.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Form(
                  onChanged: () {},
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(child: Text('a')),
                              Container(child: Text('a')),
                              Container(child: Text('a')),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(child: Text('a')),
                              Container(child: Text('a')),
                              Container(child: Text('a')),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see it in my example, maybe what is wrapping it is causing the issue? It's good to know, so I know where not to look. Thanks

Comment: The tree is Form < Container < Column < Center < Padding < Scaffold . If I do Form < Center < Padding < Scaffold then it works. Maybe the nested columns is the problem

Comment: @user3808307 I changed code like tree you provide, and change it to work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I was really liking flutter but if it is going to take me hours just to add a line, I think I might go back to react or something

Comment: It's my pleasure. Rather, I want to say 'Thank you' through your question, I also learned one more widget.